# ResolutionScale vs RawPixelsPerViewPixel on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm currently working on a universal Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1 application, and am trying to make sense of the various types of display information that's being presented to me.

For Windows Phone, we have access to two different properties in the DisplayInformationClass:

- ResolutionScale
- RawPixelsPerViewPixels

ResolutionScale seems to only be valid for certain 'tiers' like 100/140/240, while RawPixelsForViewPixels looks like it provides a precise number for the given device.  For example, on my HTC One:

- ResolutionScale: Scale180Percent
- RawPixelsPerViewPixel: 2.6

Those are pretty different values!

My assumption is that ResolutionScale should be used for bucketing more discrete items like images, where you don't have the luxury of making all kinds of sizes over a wide spectrum, wheres RawPixelsPerViewPixel can give you exact values to work with (for doing custom drawing for example).

Given that Windows.Current.Bounds gives me 415x738 in view pixels for my HTC One, and the specified resolution for my phone is 1080 x 1920, 2.6 seems correct.

However, RawPixelsPerViewPixels is only available for Windows Phone 8.1, not Windows 8.1, and I can't seem to find an equivalent over what seems to be the "approximate" ResolutionScale value described above, if I wanted a more precise number for my Windows 8.1 app.

I guess this is a 2 part question:

1) Are the assumptions about filling approximate vs actual needs as described above valid?

2) Why doesn't Windows 8.1 offer both of these as well?  Why is the ResolutionScale value the only thing available, when Windows Phone 8.1 provides both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResolutionScale` is deprecated; always use `RawPixelsPerViewPixel` for Windows Phone and for Windows 10 Universal apps.

Unfortunately, Windows 8.1 (released before Phone 8.1) still uses `ResolutionScale` so you need to continue using that property for Windows 8.1 apps.

If you are building a Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app then you need to move any scale-factor calculations out of the Shared code into platform-specific code (eg, just a helper method `GetScaleFactor()` that returns the right value for each platform).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I recognized the name from the "From 4 to 40 inches" Build video.